# Fast and efficient way to subtract arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have a large stack of images and I need to subtract, from each image, the background. The initial stack is five-dimensional and the image to subtract is two-dimensional. Subtraction works well using nested loops, but not when I switch to a `[:,:]` notation. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

In other words, this works

```
for aa in range(B.shape[0]):
    for bb in range(B.shape[1]):
        A_clean[i,j,k,aa,bb] = A[i,j,k,aa,bb] - B[aa,bb]
```

And this, which I would prefer to use because it is much faster, doesn't

```
A_clean[i,j,k,:,:] = A[i,j,k,:,:] - B[:,:]
```

`A`, `A_clean` and `B` are all numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do as you require ...

- Reshaping as `b = b.reshape((1,1,1,)+b.shape)`
- You can index like `b[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :]`

Below is an example and test

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((4,4,4,4,4))
b = np.zeros((4,4)) - 9999

b_adj = b.reshape((1,1,1,4,4)) # the reshape

res_validation = a.copy()
for aa in range(b.shape[0]):
    for bb in range(b.shape[1]):
        res[:,:,:,aa,bb] = a[:,:,:,aa,bb] - b[aa,bb]
```

Checking the results

```
res = a - b_adj
(res == res_validation ).all()
```

## References

- http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html